# nodejs formidable not triggering any events

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I am on express3.x and using formidable

```
app.post "/up",(req,res)->
formidable = require('formidable')
form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
form.uploadDir = __dirname + "/uploads"
form.encoding = 'binary'


form.addListener 'file',(name,file) ->
    #write file
    console.log('file uploaded')
    return
console.log('$$$$$$$$$$$')
form.addListener 'end', ->
    console.log('end')
    res.end()
    return
console.log('@@@@@$$$$')
form.parse req,(err,fields,files)->
    console.log('parse')
    console.log(err) if(err)
    return
console.log('######')
return
```

and the upload form is

```
block content
:coffeescript
    $ ->
        formData = new FormData()
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        onProgress = (e)->
            per_complete = (e.loaded/e.total) * 100 if e.lengthComputable

        onReady = (e)->
            alert("Ready")

        onError = (err)->
            alert("Error Loading "+err)

        $('#upload').click (e)->
            formData.append('img',document.getElementById('img').files[0])
            xhr.open('post','/up',true)
            xhr.addEventListener('error',onError,false)
            xhr.addEventListener('progress',onProgress,false)
            xhr.send(formData)
            xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange',onReady,false)

h1 hello world
form
    |select Image: 
    input(type='file',name='img', id='img')
    input(type='button',value='button', id='upload')
```

none of events are getting triggered...Not sure what am I my missing..

Answer (score 3):

if you use `app.use(express.bodyParser())`
is equivalent to:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
```

you can remove `app.use(express.multipart());` then you can use formidable object.

Answer (score 2):

express is using formidable internally, so your formidable doesn't get any events, if you would like to use formidable on your own you have to remove `multipart/form-data` from the bodyParser

i am still on express 2.x but that should also do the trick on 3.x, in your app.configure function try

```
app.configure(function(){
  delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data']
})
```

now you can use formidable on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you are using formidable and not the built in [bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html)? It uses the [multipart](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) middleware and is based on formidable. Therefore most of the options from [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) can also be applied to the bodyParser. For example:

```
app.use(connect.multipart({ uploadDir: path }));
```

To answer your question, try the following code:

app.js

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.img)
  res.end()
})
```

index.jade

```
form
  input(type="file", name="img", id="img")
  input(type="button", value="button", id="upload")
script
  var formdata = new FormData()
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  $("#upload").on("click", function(e) {            
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
      console.log("While sending and loading data.")
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        console.log (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
      }
    }

    xhr.onloadend = function(evt) {
      console.log("When the request has completed (either in success or failure).")
    }

    xhr.onload = function(evt) {
      console.log("When the request has successfully completed.")
    }

    var image = document.getElementById('img').files[0]
    formdata.append("img", image)
    xhr.open("POST", "/", true)
    xhr.send(formdata)
  })
```

Have a look at the [W3C Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#event-handlers) for more events.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in which the file was uploaded completly before My controller got arround to proccessing it. The events were fired but I wasn't listening yet.
To counter act this I wrote a middleware to capture file uploads and keep them around for controller to access later.

https://gist.github.com/3813103

you can implement it with

```
var fileHandler = require('./middleware/fileHandler');
app.use(fileHandler());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nodejs / Express Setup**

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable
npm install express-formidable
```

**Quick Demo**

```
const express = require('express');
const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable');

const app = express();

// Express-Formidable attaches your multi-part form to the request object
app.use('/formdata/with-fields-and-files', formidableMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.fields, 'fields')
   console.log(req.files, 'files')
}

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happened today.
Wasted 4+ hours of time.
Was expecting an answer here, but din't find it here, so writing it.

**Problem**

```
1. formidable - fileBegin event is     fired  
2. formidable - file      event is     fired - for small ~3MB/~4MB files
3. formidable - file      event is not fired - for large files

on local machine - nodejs/libraries will work fine
on remote machine - behind nginx it above issue happens
```

Libraries used:
- micro - https://github.com/zeit/micro            - main culprit due to too easy programming model
- formidable - https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable - smaller culprit does not give example of async/await

**Solution**

```
1. increase the VM memory size 2/3 times the file upload size (libraries eat a lot of memory)
2. increase both proxy & http timeout/ size in the nginx to the required
    - example, 10 mins timeout & 2G size
3. change the programming model for large files
    a. on local machine - nodejs/libraries will work fine
    b. but behind the nginx proxy, it optimizes and kills the on going process asap
        to solve this proxy issue, use more promises/ async-awaits, delay the reply to nginx
```

Hope that helps.